# kohana validate orm in modal window

Tags: ajax, action, modal-dialog, kohana

I have controller action like this:

```
public function action_add() {
    $this->template->content = View::factory('frontend/content/add_video')
            ->bind('video', $video)
            ->bind('errors', $errors);
    $video = new Model_Video();
    if ($this->request->post()) {
        $video->values($this->request->post(), array('source', 'title', 'description'));
        try {
            $video->save();
        } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
            $errors = $e->errors('video');
        }
    }
}
```

The view for this action is displayed in modal window. The window is openen with jquery.
When the form is validated it is displayed on reguler window, not in the modal window.
How to get the form valdates in modal? Should i use ajax call to get this to work?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AJAX, but return only:

```
    if($this->request->is_ajax()) {
        echo View::factory('frontend/content/add_video')
            ->bind('video', $video)
            ->bind('errors', $errors);
       exit;
    }
```